# Android Sync adapter implementation

Tags: android, synchronization

I need some sample project or tutorials site for learning Android Sync Adapter. Information and the sample project from google was not sufficient for my understanding please help me with the links where i can learn a simple sync adapter.

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Comment: You can reading this : https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2018/06/android-sync-adapter.html

Answer (score 1):

To create a SyncAdapter you need to implement a few things before:

- Authenticator: Check this [amazing tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/).
- Content provider: [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).
- A simple [service class](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#CreateSyncAdapterService).
- The [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#CreateSyncAdapter) class.

You will need an API with which synchronize your data.

If you want more information, check the [Udinic tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/) about this topic.